# How to enable lttng_statedump events?

Tags: lttng

I receive letting_statedump events when I enable these events and start the tracing. I noticed that I receive this only once for the life of the trace session. How would I initiate the generation of statedump events without stopping the trace and restarting?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way at the moment to trigger a statedump manually.

However I would ask, why would you need to do so? The goal of the statedump is for trace viewers or analysers to be able to have an idea of the initial state of the system. Afterwards, they can use the actual trace events to update their state trackers.

If you do not wish to write your own state tracker, another option that may help are the [event contexts](http://lttng.org/docs/#doc-adding-context). If you enable a context like `pid` or `procname`, that information will be dumped as part of every trace event. This can be used to get up-to-date state information more easily. You can use

```
lttng add-context --help
```

to list the available contexts.